# html tag becomes to uppercase when get innerHTML by webbrowser

Tags: html

All html tags goes to uppercase letters when get body's innerHTML  by webbrowser.
how should I do to get the real htmlcode?

Comment: that is the expected behavior

Comment: What do you really want to do ? What is the point of getting the original html ? Are you trying to parse HTML (really bad idea) ?

Comment: i have a textbox which write the original html code, and i use the webbrowser navigate to the textbox text string. i want rewrite the textbox's text when the webbrowser's html code has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the "real" HTML code from `innerHTML`.

By the time you read `innerHTML`, the HTML has already been parsed to a DOM and then discarded. `innerHTML` will serialise the DOM to HTML, it won't give you the original HTML.

The only way to get the original HTML would be to use `XMLHttpRequest` to get a fresh copy of the source code from the server and then parse it with a custom parser instead of the one built into the browser.

Comment: `a custom parser instead of the one built into the browser` really bad advice I think

Comment: @singe31 — The one built into the browser will normalise the case of tags and attributes, which the OP doesn't want. There isn't another client side option to achieve what is being asked for.

Comment: Yes, but what is being asked shouldn't been asked, that's what I'm saying. So, such a question shouldn't been answered because this is a really bad practice.